# Canny edge detector with kernel size > 7

Tags: c++, opencv, edge-detection

why is it not possible to perform Canny edge detection in OpenCV with a kernel size bigger than 7?

e.g.,

```
// This works
cv::Canny(src_image, out_edges, th1, 2 * th1, 3);
cv::Canny(src_image, out_edges, th1, 2 * th1, 7);

// This raises an exception
cv::Canny(src_image, out_edges, th1, 2 * th1, 9);
```

I know Sobel only takes kernel sizes of 1, 3, 5 or 7. But I've seen papers using kernel size of 9. Is this not possible in OpenCV?

*** Edit ***

I have been editing the Canny code to support larger kernels. The problem resides in here (canny.cpp):

```
if (L2gradient)
{
  low_thresh = std::min(32767.0, low_thresh);
  high_thresh = std::min(32767.0, high_thresh);
  if (low_thresh > 0) low_thresh *= low_thresh;
  if (high_thresh > 0) high_thresh *= high_thresh;
}
```

and

```
if (L2gradient)
{
  low_thresh = std::min(32767.0, low_thresh);
  high_thresh = std::min(32767.0, high_thresh);

  if (low_thresh > 0) low_thresh *= low_thresh;
  if (high_thresh > 0) high_thresh *= high_thresh;
}
```

I guess this is related to the fact that they are using some shift operation,

```
#define CANNY_SHIFT 15
const int TG22 = (int)(0.4142135623730950488016887242097*(1<<CANNY_SHIFT) + 0.5);
```

Thus limiting the precision to 16 bits, therefore the 32767 limit.... How could I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the OpenCV doc:

For [Canny](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga04723e007ed888ddf11d9ba04e2232de):

> **apertureSize:** aperture size for the Sobel operator.

And for [Sobel](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gacea54f142e81b6758cb6f375ce782c8d):

> **ksize:** size of the extended Sobel kernel; it must be 1, 3, 5, or 7.

So the aperture size in `Canny` is limited by the `Sobel` kernel size.

This is verified in the [source code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/canny.cpp#L609-L610) :

```
 if ((aperture_size & 1) == 0 || (aperture_size != -1 && (aperture_size < 3 || aperture_size > 7)))
    CV_Error(CV_StsBadFlag, "Aperture size should be odd");
```

So, unless you rewrite yourself some code, there's no way to use Canny with a larger aperture size. You can apply your custom *large sobel filter* with [filter2d](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html), and then code the Canny non maxima suppression.

However, Sobel with mask larger then 3x3 is rarely used in practice.

Comment: Hey Miki! I found out the reason for their limit to the kernel size. I edited my question. Do you have any idea on how could I solve this?

Comment: @manatttta I'm not entirely sure that the shift does what you meant. The code is so optimized that is very difficult to read. However, if you rewrite the NMS part, you should be able to work with larger kernel sizes. Again, I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: In Opencv 3.1.0 and above you can pass the gradients as input to canny edge detector.. Find gradients using the desired kernel and pass this as input to Canny... [see here] (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga04723e007ed888ddf11d9ba04e2232de)